# grep any word with any groups of (non-overlapping) consecutive letters

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to grep any word that has any specified groups of consecutive letters, and those groups must not overlap. To be specific, for example ,say I want to find 2 groups of consecutive letters, I have tried the following command, but it didn't work.
PS: sample is a txt file that contains a word in each line.

```
grep -iE '.*([a-z])\1..*([a-z])\1.*' sample
```

Comment: Please show the contents of *sample* and your expected output.

Comment: For example, there is a word 'Russell' in the sample documents then my command should be able to grep this word while distinguishing words like shannon, woody ...

Comment: 'Russell' does not have "groups of consecutive letters"

Comment: @Iplouis Please add the content of *sample* to your question

Comment: @alfasin ss and ll are two groups of consecutive letters? Right?

Comment: These are not "consecutive letters" but rather "repeating letters". "ab" are consecutive and so are "bc" and etc.

Comment: @Iplouis - third request: Please show the contents of `sample` and your expected output.

Comment: @alfasin `ab` aren't consecutive in all locales. In some locales `A` comes between `a` and `b` because `[a-z]` means `[aAbBcC....yYz]`, i.e. all upper or lower case letters except `Z`. Nothing to stop some locales having non-letters in the middle either I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it.

```
$ echo "russell" | grep -iE '([a-z])\1.*([a-z])\2'
russell
```

The main functional difference is that the second back-reference must be `\2` in order to refer to the second bracketed expression.

Other differences .. the leading and trailing `.*` seemed redundant, and you appeared to have an extra dot in the middle of the expression.  The dot would match any character, so it would allow `aabcc` to match, but not `aabb`.

Comment: Good catch about the extra dot!

Comment: Thanks .. though in retrospect, I wonder if the OP's condition that they "must not overlap" actually meant that there should be something between them.  We shall see. :)

Comment: I took `not overlap` as meaning `aaa` shoudn't be considered as `aa` and `aa` but there's a ton of other unanswered questions and without sample input and expected output we're all just guessing...

Answer (score 1):

You were close, change your regex from:

```
'.*([a-z])\1..*([a-z])\1.*'
```

to:

```
'.*([a-z])\1..*([a-z])\2.*'
```

The second back reference should refer to the second captured group - not to the first.